# Data format for storing multiple nested JSON files

Tags: python, json, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have approximately 2000 JSON files that look (roughly) like this:

```
{
  "hist": {
    "type": "TH2",
    "title": "The Title of the Plot",
    "stats": {
      "name": "The Title of the Plot",
      "entries": 720135.0,
    },
    "xaxis": {
      "title": "The X Axis label",
      "first": {
        "id": 1,
        "value": -3
      },
      "last": {
        "id": 31,
        "value": 3
      }
    },
    "yaxis": {
      "title": "The X Axis label",
      "first": {
        "id": 1,
        "value": -3.14159
      },
      "last": {
        "id": 32,
        "value": 3.14159
      }
    },
    "values": {
      "min": 0,
      "max": 1434
    },
    "bins": {
      "content": [
        [
          17,
          392,
          1185
        ],
        [
          14,
          424,
          1083
        ],
        [
          8,
          392,
          1030
        ],
        [
          4,
          226,
          965
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What i am most interested in is the `entries` value and the `content`. The `content` of a real JSON file can be either a 32x31 or a 32x26 matrix.

Each JSON file is uniquely identifiable by the file name.

I have to run calculations on the content and have to be able to plot the content itself like this:

```py
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(json_file['hist']['bins']['content'])
```

Since the JSON file is nested, I'm not sure how to store it in a `pandas` data frame. I guess most of the properties except `contents` can be flattened, but I don't know how to flatten a (variable size) matrix.

What could be a suitable data format to store all 2000 JSON files?

Comment: A list of dataframes?

Comment: How would that dataframe look like? I am not sure how i can use a matrix as a column value (and if that's even efficient)